# Dart classes requires implementation of Object ==

Tags: flutter, class, dart, compiler-errors

While I was coding suddenly all my files turned red and required an implementation and removing the constructors const keyword. So I'm confused is it an update for dart classes to require this implementation or something else.

[image]

[image]

Here is one example class:

```
    class Message {
      final String userId;
      final String messageText;
      final DateTime sentAt;
      DocumentReference? reference;

      Message({
        required this.userId,
        required this.messageText,
        required this.sentAt,
        this.reference,
      });

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            'userId': userId,
            'messageText': messageText,
            'sentAt': sentAt.toString(),
          };

      factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Message(
          userId: json['userId'] ?? "",
          messageText: json['messageText'] ?? "",
          sentAt: DateTime.parse(json['sentAt'] as String),
        );
      }
      factory Message.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
        final message = Message.fromJson(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
        return message;
      }
      // Without this operator there is a compile error.
      @override
      operator ==(Object other) {
        // TODO: implement ==
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    }
```

Comment: include your class instead of structure image.  also try `flutter pub get`

Comment: I tried pub get nothing changed and restarted VS code also, at first there is no errors then sometime later all the files will turn red.

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: Updated it, please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Equatable`](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package for equality. and to use `const` contractor, all fields needed to be final.

```dart
class Message extends Equatable {
  final String userId;
  final String messageText;
  final DateTime sentAt;
  final DocumentReference? reference;

  const Message({
    required this.userId,
    required this.messageText,
    required this.sentAt,
    this.reference,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'userId': userId,
        'messageText': messageText,
        'sentAt': sentAt.toString(),
      };

  factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Message(
      userId: json['userId'] ?? "",
      messageText: json['messageText'] ?? "",
      sentAt: DateTime.parse(json['sentAt'] as String),
    );
  }
  factory Message.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    final message = Message.fromJson(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
    return message;
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [userId, messageText, sentAt, reference];

  Message copyWith({
    String? userId,
    String? messageText,
    DateTime? sentAt,
    DocumentReference? reference,
  }) {
    return Message(
      userId: userId ?? this.userId,
      messageText: messageText ?? this.messageText,
      sentAt: sentAt ?? this.sentAt,
      reference: reference ?? this.reference,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not the problem. I don't want to use Equatable, and It's not only model classes but state classes as well all require an implementation which I don't need. even MyApp() widget needs this implementation.

Comment: is it possible you;ve edited the source code? try `flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: No, nothing changes, tried it multiple times.